# Laravel validation name without polish letters

Tags: php, validation, laravel

Hi I have a method to change polish letters on normal letters. For example:

> **łódź** change to **lodz**

or

> **Michał** change to **Michal**

```
private $letter = array( 'Ę', 'Ó', 'Ą', 'Ś', 'Ł', 'Ż', 'Ź', 'Ć', 'Ń', 'ę', 'ó', 'ą', 
    'ś', 'ł', 'ż', 'ź', 'ć', 'ń' );
private $change = array( 'E', 'O', 'A', 'S', 'L', 'Z', 'Z', 'C', 'N', 'e', 'o', 'a', 
    's', 'l', 'z', 'z', 'c', 'n' );

public function changeLetter( $string )
{
    $string = str_replace( $this->letter, $this->change, $string );
    $string = preg_replace( '#[^a-z0-9]#is', ' ', $string );
    $string = trim( $string );

    return $string;
}
```

And method to save new record to database:

```
public function store(CreateWarehouseRequest $request){
    $downloadNameWarehouse = Input::get('name_warehouse');
    $changeLetter = $this->changeLetter($downloadNameWarehouse);
    $warehouse = new warehouse($request->all());

    Auth::user()->warehouses()->save($warehouse);
```

}

How I can add validation changeLetter to method `store`?

Comment: Why do you actually want to mutilate the original text?

Comment: `changeLetter` is not a validation...

Comment: @MarkBaker Because method stroy created new table in databse and when the name is with polsih letters, then Laravel returned error: **SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1300 Invalid utf8 character string: 'warehouses_la\xE5\x82\xE4\x85\xE4\x85\xE4\x85_9_product_id_forei' (SQL: alter table `warehouses_lałąąą_9` add constraint `warehouses_la����_9_product_id_foreign` foreign key (`product_id`) references `products` (`id`))**

Comment: Then enforce UTF-8, converting if necessary.... but this smells strongly of bad database design

Comment: That's an alter table statement and I think Laravel determines the name of the key based on the columns of the tables being related.  You might have to write a raw statement to create that foreign key, but then you shouldn't have any troubles actually inserting utf8 data so you shouldn't need to modify names.

Comment: Have a look at [iconv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php)

Comment: Or [transliterator_transliterate](http://php.net/manual/en/transliterator.transliterate.php) or you could use something like [behat/transliterator](https://github.com/Behat/Transliterator)